# Settings related to reading QR codes

Tags: settings, qr-code, google-authenticator

I wanted to use the Google Authenticator app to set up two factor authentication. However when I click on the button to scan a QR code, it opens up a camera with 'NAB Banking' at the top (my internet banking app). When I scan a code, it says 'Oops! This isn't a valid BPAY code.' (see screenshot below)

Is there some settings related to using the camera for QR code scanning, that my internet banking app has taken 'hostage'?  (That I might hopefully be able to clear?) I didn't have the NAB app open at the time, and as far as I remember I have never used the QR code scanning from within it.

Versions:

- Google Authenticator 2.49
- [NAB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.nab.mobile): 3.0.1
- Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3, GT-19305, Android version 4.1.2

[image: qr codes taken hostage by nab]

Comment: Could you try to go to the Settings > Apps > NAB Banking page and tap "Clear Defaults"? Does this still happen after clearing the defaults for NAB Banking?

Comment: @dotVezz it already says "no defaults set".

Comment: Stupid question: Do you have any QR reader installed at all? Maybe your banking app is the only one registered for barcode reading. No other candidate, no other choice.

Comment: @Izzy good point. I just installed [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tingiz&hl=en) which reads QR codes if I open it directly, but if I use the Google Authenticator app it still goes to the NAB reader.

Comment: One more guess: maybe it can not be "any" QR app, but needs to be a specific one. Many apps use the ZXing library for barcodes, so you might give the [ZXing Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/barcode-scanner/com.google.zxing.client.android) a try (though I prefer [QR Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/QR-Droid/la.droid.qr) :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your issue can be found on [the app's help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en). As I already guessed, you need to install a barcode reader app. But not just "any", ist has to be a specific one. And moreover, even my guess for [ZXing Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/barcode-scanner/com.google.zxing.client.android) was absolutely correct – if you take a closer look at the screenshot taken from that place:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot from the [Google Authenticator help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en) (click image for original size)</sup>

Btw: The name "ZXing" stands for Zebra Crossing, but I doubt it can decode the Zebra's natural barcodes :)

As it reportedly works as well in this context, I recommend using [QR Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/qr-droid%E2%84%A2/la.droid.qr) if you want to use the QR Reader for additional tasks as well. *QR Droid* has a much nicer interface, offers additional features, and gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: [QR Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/qr-droid%E2%84%A2/la.droid.qr) works too. I think you just need a QR Reader that doesn't limit you to some form of data, and Google provided the most popular to help users that don't know :)

Comment: If [QR Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/qr-droid%E2%84%A2/la.droid.qr) works as well, as Shywim suggests, I'd prefer that over *ZXing* as it gives you much more flexibility (and has a nicer GUI ;)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, great detective work! I installed QR Droid and now [it works](http://flic.kr/p/jD7qGa). No idea how you found that help page. Would be good if it was linked from the app itself.

Comment: That's how I found it: It's linked from the app's description on Google Play, directly :) // One PS: My guess is your banking app also uses the ZXing library, and exposed its intents – so GA thought it detected the ZXing Reader itself... Thanks for the feedback on QR Droid, confirming Shywim. I will include that with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe install a QR code reader from the app store. That's what I did when setting up Authenticator.

Comment: I just tried that, but Google Authenticator still goes to the NAB app camera.

Comment: @pfctdayelise: In settings -> Applications -> NAB Banking -> tap on `Clear Defaults`